# Is the noun after werden when using it as full Verben always in nominative case?

Tags: grammatical-case, nominative

[image: Google Translater]

In this image it should have been "einen Vogel" if it is in Akkusativ Case. Can someone explain this please.

Comment: I suggest to replace the bulky graphics by text, to enhance support for screen readers.

Comment: Why do you think *werden* should take an accusative object? What does a dictionary say?

Comment: "werden" - if used in the sense of "to become" - always has the nominative on both sides: "Ich werde irgendwann der Präsident von Österreicht".

Answer (score 3):

There are some verbs *(Kopulaverben)* that don't describe something being done, but assign a property to the subject of the sentence.

> *Das Haus* ist *blau*. (The house is blue.)
> *Dein Auto* ist *ein Audi*. (Your car is an Audi.)
> *Ich* werde *Bäcker*. (I'll become a baker.)
> *Sam* bleibt *der CEO* von OpenAI. (Sam stays CEO of OpenAI.)
> *Dieser Typ Lampe* heißt *Stehlampe*. (This type of lamp is called a floor lamp.)

The assigned property is called a **Prädikativ** (predicative) and, for nouns, is in the same *casus* (grammatical case) as the noun to which it is assigned. In the example sentences above and in the sentence from the question that's nominative.

With another class of verbs, predicatives can also appear as objects:

> Sie nannte *ihn* immer wieder *einen Lügner*. (She called him a liar again and again.)

Answer (score 1):

The complement of "werden" is nominative most of the time, but not always nominative case. This is because, as Halvar said, the case of a predicative is agreement case. It changes with the source of the agreement.

- Der Urlaub wird ein Erfolg (2 x Nom)
- Lassen Sie den Urlaub einen Erfolg werden (2 x Acc)

(From: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Der_Kasus_von_substantivischen_Pr%C3%A4dikativa )

The object-oriented predicative "einen Lügner" in Halva's last example works the same, it is not an object but also a predicative, and it adapts to the case of the preceding object.